# how to make a clickable link using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I got this example link below:

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sad-police-app.appspot.com/o/Time?alt=media&token=6cb588bf-182b-48be-88bd-1d2b804sdecebe

I'm displaying it on web. and i want it to be clickable. can you help me guys how to do it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please add more detail: some sample code (not a link but in the question here) and how you expected it to work, etc.

Comment: It's a link, it appears to be 'clickable' already; what do you want it to do that it's not already doing? Incidentally, please read the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines, then [edit] your question to improve it so that we can help you.

Comment: Why are you wanting it done in JavaScript when it can just be done with standard HTML?

Comment: Please read [ask] and the [help/on-topic] for information about what we expect in a question.

Comment: i'm getting that link from my firebase database and display it on web using java script. this is the code for that link "picture.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.Picture.replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/"/g, '')));" 
i want it to be clickable when displaying on web

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the code you are using. Please also [do some research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) into how to make things clickable on the web.

Answer (score -1):

You can try Parent div position Relative and anchor tag iside has pos: absolute, provide anchor with width and height

```
 <div style="position:relative">
     <img src="" width=" " height=" " />
     <a href="#" style="display:block; width:  ; height:  ; position:absolute; left: ; top: 
 ;"></a>
    </div>
```